# Why can't postgres understand a reference to a derived column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have this query:

```
select 
   id, 
   unnest(suppliers) as suppliercode
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on t1.suppliercode = t2.suppliercode
```

Postgres can't understand what is meant by:

```
on t1.suppliercode = t2.suppliercode
```

The **t2.suppliercode** is causing confusion. Why? How do you explicitly call the new derived column?

Comment: `suppliercode` is not part of `t1` -- `suppliers` is. You'd want to wrap the thing in an aliased subquery or a `with` statement to make it work.

Comment: All standards following SQL systems would have similar problems. Logically, the `SELECT` clause is processed well *after* the `FROM` clause (including joins).

Comment: "*The t2.suppliercode is causing confusion. Why?*" - because that's the way the SQL standard defined it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t1.suppliercode` means "column `suppliercode` from table `t1`". And your table `t1` doesnt have such column.

Try something like:

```
select *
from(select t1.id, 
            unnest(t1.suppliers) as suppliercode
     from table1 t1 ) sub
left join table2 t2
on sub.suppliercode = t2.suppliercode
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but what I really want to know is how to explicitly called the new derived column?

Comment: @coderama You don't, it's just not supported. You *must* use a subquery in `FROM` or a `WITH` query (common table expression).